# _react3.default.createref is not a function.(In '_react2.default.createRef()'_react2.default.createRef is undefined

Tags: react-native, react-native-instagram-login

Unable to login my app via instagram. I am using react-native instagram package, but i am facing the issue as _react3.default.creteRef() is not a function. Refer the attachment

[image]
**Environment:**

```
Packages: (wanted => installed)
  react: 16.2.0 => 16.2.0
  react-native: ^0.53.3 => 0.53.3

Xcode: Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61
npm: 5.6.0
OS: macOS 10.14.2
Node: 9.4.0
```

Comment: can you add some code where you are getting this error?

Comment: <InstagramLogin ref='ins' clientId='41412451425425425245425245451' scopes={['content+list']} onLoginSuccess={(token, result)  onLoginFailure={(data) => this.setState({failure: data})}/>

Answer (score 4):

You are using an old version of react. The createRef API was added in React 16.3.0 and you are using 16.2.0. Release notes [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/29/react-v-16-3.html)

It seems that this new API is being called from one of your dependencies, as the stacktrace mentions Instagram.js, you need to either update React, or change or downgrade that dependency.

Answer (score 2):

try changing,

`ref='ins'`

to

`ref={instance=>this.instagramRef=instance}`,

and use refs as `this.instagramRef.someFunc()` instead of `this.refs.ins.someFunc()`

and don't forget to set `this.instagramRef=null` in a constructor.

**REMOVE** all `createRef()` if used. and change to this method