# Invalid hook call hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: react-native

I am currently implementing a modal using the Modalize library. I'm using Hooks for the requests but as soon as I'm going to call the Modalize component it returns the following error. I've spent a lot of time and haven't figured out where the problem is

[image]

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { Modalize } from 'react-native-modalize';

export default class MyScreen extends React.Component {

    render() {

        const modalizeRef = useRef(null);

        function onOpen() {
            modalizeRef.current?.open();
        }

        return (
            <View>
               <TouchableOpacity onPress={onOpen}>        
                     <Text>click me</Text>
               </TouchableOpacity>

                <Modalize
                    ref={modalizeRef}
                    snapPoint={180}
                    >
                    <View
                        style={{
                            flex: 1,
                            height: 100,
                            flexDirection: 'row',
                        }}>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={[style.btnTest, { backgroundColor: '#29ae19' }]}>
                            Button 01
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                        <TouchableOpacity style={[style.btnTest, { backgroundColor: '#ff0000' }]}>
                            Button 02
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                    </View>
                </Modalize>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're only supposed to use hooks in functional components.
Read the docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

```
export default function MyScreen() {
  const modalizeRef = useRef(null);

  function onOpen() {
      modalizeRef.current?.open();
  }

  return (
      <View>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={onOpen}>        
                <Text>click me</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

          <Modalize
              ref={modalizeRef}
              snapPoint={180}
              >
              <View
                  style={{
                      flex: 1,
                      height: 100,
                      flexDirection: 'row',
                  }}>
                  <TouchableOpacity style={[style.btnTest, { backgroundColor: '#29ae19' }]}>
                      Button 01
                  </TouchableOpacity>

                  <TouchableOpacity style={[style.btnTest, { backgroundColor: '#ff0000' }]}>
                      Button 02
                  </TouchableOpacity>

              </View>
          </Modalize>
      </View>
  );

}
```

Comment: u can only use hooks in function components(function and arrow). you have to convert the class component to a functional component.

Comment: Is there any other alternative to make this work without using hooks? How should I do this?

Comment: @RoktSe [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rkajup?file=src/App.js) is a class version of it

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather you want a ref.
there are 2 ways

1. declare it in constructor using createRef(no import needed)

   ```
   constructor(props){
    this.modalizeRef = React.createRef();
   }
   ```
2. assign it in the component call

   ```
    <Modalize
       ref={(ref) => {
          this.modalizeRef = ref;
        }}
     />
   ```

Comment: This return the following error: "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating _this.modalizeRef = _react.default.CreateRef)" @Glitch_Znab

Comment: Check this usage. https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html and also this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55514308/12370254

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by doing this using the [refs callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs)

```
  export default class MyScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.modalizeRef = React.createRef();
    }

    onOpen() {
        this.modalizeRef.current?.open();
    }

}


<View>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onOpen.bind(this)}>        
                <Text>click me</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

          <Modalize
              ref={this.modalizeRef}
              snapPoint={180}
              >
              <View
                  style={{
                      flex: 1,
                      height: 100,
                      flexDirection: 'row',
                  }}>
                  <TouchableOpacity style={[style.btnTest, { backgroundColor: '#29ae19' }]}>
                      Button 01
                  </TouchableOpacity>

                  <TouchableOpacity style={[style.btnTest, { backgroundColor: '#ff0000' }]}>
                      Button 02
                  </TouchableOpacity>

              </View>
          </Modalize>
      </View>
```